# Unix cat command, pipe and stdin/stdout

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, pipe, stdin

Here is something I don't understand.

Why this works : `echo "akka" | cat`

But this does not produce "akka" on the console : `echo "akka" > cat`

And this does not even work : `cat < echo "akka"`

For me they should be the same. But these 3 commands seem different

Comment: Pipes and *redirection* are two very different things. In short and very simplified: A pipe connect two programs; While redirection, well, *redirects* to (or from) a file.

Comment: `>` redirects stdout _to a file_. `echo "akka" >cat` works correctly: It creates a file named `cat` in your current directory.

Comment: ...and `cat < echo "akka"` (being identical to `cat "akka" <echo`) redirects stdin _from_ a file, so it tries to open a file named `echo`, and feed its contents to the stdin of the command `cat "akka"`. If no file named `echo` exists it fails (and it's unlikely to do anything useful anyhow, because `cat "akka"` reads only from the file `akka`; it ignores anything connected to its stdin, such as any contents of the file named `echo`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are confusing the differences between file redirection and piping.

The pipe symbol `|` is used to pass the output of one command into another command.

Meanwhile, `<` and `>` are used for file redirection.

These are very different operations.

**Example 1:**

```
echo "akka" | cat
```

The `echo` command has the output `akka`, and this is piped into the standard input of the `cat` command. The `cat` command writes to standard output, so in this case it prints `akka`. Of course, this is no different from doing simply:

```
echo "akka"
```

**Example 2:**

```
echo "akka" > cat
```

The `echo` command has the output `akka`. Using `>`, this output is then redirected into a file called `cat`. There is no output shown in the terminal in this case, since the output is placed into a file instead.

**Example 3:**

```
cat < echo "akka"
```

This is quite different from the first two. This runs the `cat` command, which reads from standard input. Using `<`, input is passed to the `cat` command from a file called `echo`. If no such files exists, then it will produce an error.

Comment: @charles I actually couldn't find a suitable duplicate in this case. If you can find one, please suggest it. Are you saying the question is not well-asked?

Comment: Working on the duplicate list now.

Comment: @charles though the linked duplicate is related, I feel like my answer provides a more relevant discussion that covers the 3 cases in the question. I did search for duplicates and found that, but I didn't feel it addressed this question well enough, particularly the 3rd case mentioned by the OP. Hence, why I provided an answer in this case.

Comment: Yup. After spending a bit more time looking at the difference between this question and its predecessors, I do think answering is defensible here; for that matter, I sometimes add a community-wiki answer myself when there's something that's duplicative, but where it's not immediately obvious how to apply the duplicates.

Comment: ok thanks. So basically 'cat < myFile' is the same as 'cat myFile', correct ?

Comment: Not exactly. `cat < myFile` will use file redirection to pass the contents of the file `myFile` to the standard input of `cat`, while `cat myFile` will pass the filename to `cat` (as a command-line argument), and cat will open the file and read it. In the second case, the `cat` command has the filename, while in the first case, the `cat` command doesn't deal directly with the file and only reads from standard input.

Comment: Though they do achieve the same thing in this case, the difference is with the latter, you can supply multiple filenames as arguments and `cat` will concatenate the contents of those files (e.g. `cat myFile1 myFile2`), while using the former, you pass the contents of just one file.